# Need help on authorization/token generation via OAuth2 using Fiddler

Tags: oauth2

I am trying to generate access token using **Fiddler** and results in error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"authentication failure"}
```

The same request I tried from the **POSTMAN** and its working fine.

Below are the steps that I am following in fiddler :

**METHOD**: POST

**ENDPOINT URL** : https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

**REQUEST BODY** client_id={Client-ID}&client_secret={Client-Secret}&grant_type=password&username={UserName}&password={Password}

***NOTE** - However, I observed that when the same request I hit from POSTMAN and consecutively later from Fiddler it is generating the access token. Although if I hit the same request independently from fiddler its results in above error.

Comment: Did you try adding the security token to password?

Comment: @Prasanna Yes we tried that too

Comment: Does external system required any IP WhiteListing ?

Comment: @NachiketDeshpande: IP is already whitelisted.